# Ubuntu LTS20.04 night light is coming ahead of time

Tags: 20.04

Basically my night light feature is activated before the time set begins. An image is worth 1000 words in this case:

[image]

As you can see the time is 17:43 and night light should start at 18:00 but night light is already on at 17:43. Very very weird.

The proof that night light is on.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The night light starts to take effect earlier than the time set so that the user becomes accustomed to the change before it takes full effect.

It is a gradual process rather than an instant change.

There's a useful reference [here](https://www.askdavetaylor.com/enable-night-light-mode-in-ubuntu-linux/)